# Rails + Bootstrap + IE8 : .col doesn't work

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I have a little probelm with Bootstrap.

When i'm on Chrome, my website is absolutely gorgeous, with perfect colonne (.col-md-6)
In IE9 : the website is good.
But in IE8: it's crap, all my .col-md- is 100% width !

I put this on header :

```
/[if IE 8]
 = javascript_include_tag "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"
 = javascript_include_tag "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"
```

But doesn't fix the problem !

Thanks for your help !

Comment: any console errors or sth?

Comment: Have you checked the Respond.js stuff mentioned on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9 ?

Comment: Does this `if` block come before or after the `<link>` for your CSS?